# How to make windows xp look like ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp

How to make windows xp look like ubuntu?

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: Why do you not want to?

Comment: Why don't you install ubuntu, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these:

[Ubuntu themes for Windows](http://techpp.com/2009/02/13/ultimate-collection-ubuntu-themes-visual-styles-for-windows-xp-vista/)

Disclaimer: I've not tried any of them, so use them at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

**[Make Windows XP Looks Like Ubuntu](http://www.bloganything.net/871/make-windows-xp-looks-like-ubuntu)**

**[Ubuntu Themes for XP](http://download.chip.eu/en/Ubuntu-Themes-for-XP_3812154.html)**